# Pasting a character as a token

Tags: c, character, token

I'm wondering if it's possible to paste a character as a token in C at runtime. Something like,

```
a = OPERATION(3, 4, '+')
```

will be processed to,

```
a = 3 + 4
```

Is there a way to do this?

**Edit:** I wanted to add some more information. Obviously this can't be done with the preprocessor. I'm wondering if there's a short way to do,

```
int i;
char sign[] = "+-*/";
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  printf("%d\n", OPERATION(3, 5, sign[i]));
```

I know we can create a function as,

```
int OPERATION(int a, int b, char c);
```

But this is not what I'm asking.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to get the preprocessor to do this.

Comment: Then why is it a character in the first place?

Comment: This way I can create a character array and paste the appropriate token when needed. For example, I can iterate through the character array and change the operation everytime.

Comment: Well obviously this can't be done with the preprocessor, I just realized that it's not possible. Anyways is there any other way then writing an if statement like "IF '+' THEN a + b, ELSEIF '-' THEN a - b".

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want something that happens at runtime to be processed into code at compile time, without the preprocessor. However, C is a static language, in which compilation happens *before* runtime. Compilers lack precognition.

Comment: Is there a shortcut to doing this, rather than tackling the problem on a case by case basis? For instance, as per the example in the question, is there a shorter way then writing a function to check all four conditions which are '+', '-', '*', '/'?

Comment: Andy, I'm pretty new to C and programming languages. I think for what I'm asking, there should be a something like a "C Interpreter" that runs at runtime along the program that tokenizes and interprets the character, am I right?

Comment: Simple tokenizing can be done with strtok(). More complex can be done with yacc et al. If you want an interpreter to parse and execute statements, you could choose to embed an interpreter in your application -- there is not a C interpreter available by default.

Comment: Well, that's much more work than writing a code that checks all the cases :) Thanks so much for the information!

Comment: You'd better choose another launguage, if you want to have tokens at runtime. C runtime knows nothing about C syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
#define OPERATION( A, B, OP )   ((A) OP (B))
```

However, as delnan notes below, you would have to modify your call to:

```
a = OPERATION(3, 4, +)
```

Comment: don't forget the parentheses around A and B!

Comment: Well I completely understand that that is possible but I want to use a character, this is not the answer. But thanks anyways.

Comment: This is not the answer, but I'm choosing this as the answer because of Andy's comments to the question itself, they answered my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this:

```
#define OPERATION(a, b, op) ( \
    (op) == '+' ? (a) + (b) : \
    (op) == '-' ? (a) - (b) : \
    (op) == '*' ? (a) * (b) : \
    (op) == '/' ? (a) / (b) : 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#define OPERATION(A,B,OP)     (OP=='+'?(A)+(B):OP=='-'?(A)-(B):OP=='*'?(A)*(B):OP=='/'?(A)/(B):NULL)
```

`OPERATION(3,5,'+')`  returns `8`
`OPERATION(9,2,'/')`  returns `4`
`OPERATION(9,3,'*')`  returns `27`
`OPERATION(3,5,'-')`  returns `-2`
`OPERATION(3,5,'M')`  returns `0`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not what I'm looking for. I'm wondering if there's a way to paste a character as a token at runtime.

Comment: @evothur - this answer actually solves you 'run-time' requirement. It does what you want, given the code sample you added in your question.

Comment: Yeah I know but I don't want a "case by case" code. I'm wondering if there's a way to just write any character and use it as a token. But I think this is not possible.